# Fusioncharts 3D with CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, graph, fusioncharts

I have two table

```
Table 1 : Zone        Table 2 : Tonnage
id  zonename          id  zoneid   tones  date
1     A               1    1        9.96    15-12-2012
2     B               2    2       62.26    15-12-2012
3     C               3    3       123      15-12-2012
4     D               4    4       190      15-12-2012
                      5    1       50       30-12-2012
                      6    2       45       30-12-2012
                      7    3       78       30-12-2012
                      8    4       90       30-12-2012
```

I want create a MSColumn3D chart with fusion charts. The A,B,C,D should be in the X-axis and tones should be in the y-axis. 
   This is the sql statement I have :

```
SELECT zone.zonename,tonnage.tonnes,tonnage.date
FROM zone, tonnage
WHERE zone.id = tonnage.zoneid ORDER BY ZONE.zonename;
```

I want the data of A,B,C and D grouped together and displayed based on the tonnage 
But it is not giving the right output to be displayed. How can I formulate the sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26fa1/3)**

```
SELECT z.zonename,
       SUM(t.tones) AS TotalTones
FROM Zone z
JOIN Tonnage t
ON z.id = t.zoneid 
GROUP BY z.zonename
ORDER BY z.zonename
```

Result:

```
| ZONENAME | TOTALTONES |
-------------------------
|        A |      59.96 |
|        B |     107.26 |
|        C |        201 |
|        D |        280 |
```